# Thinking Sphinx - sort across multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

To display a directory, I'm doing a search to get lots of items across various models, that all begin with a particular letter like this

```
@everything = ThinkingSphinx.search(
               "@name ^?",
               @letter,
              :match_mode => :extended,
              :classes => [Performer, Promoter, Tour, Venue, User],
              :order => :name_sort,
              :sort_mode => :asc
              )
```

However the items are not sorted alphabetically.  If I change asc to desc, the order changes but it's still in no discernable pattern.

The indexes are set up like this

```
performer.rb
define_index do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes description
  has created_at, updated_at
end


promoter.rb
define_index do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes description
  has created_at, updated_at
end


tour.rb
define_index do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes description
  has created_at, updated_at
end

venue.rb
define_index do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes description
  has created_at, updated_at
end

user.rb
define_index do
  indexes first_name, :sortable => true
  indexes last_name, :as => :name, :sortable => true
  indexes bio
  has role, created_at, updated_at
end
```

As you can see the user index aliases last_name as name, but that's the only oddity.

I'm using thinking sphinx 2.0.12

Comment: What version of sphinx are you using?

Comment: Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)

Comment: In order for your sorting to work correctly, your going to want to update your sphinx to version 2.0.6, which is the latest, your thinking sphinx version is correct though, try that and see how that works out for you.